# Print first few lines of a text file in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a text file with no apparent tabular or other structure, for example with contents

```
some text on line 1
some more text on line 2
even more text on the third line
etc
```

What is the most elegant and R-like way to print out the first few (say 2) lines of text from this file to the console?

**Option 1**: `readLines`

```
readLines('file.txt', n=2)
# [1] "some text on line 1"      "some more text on line 2"
```

The `n=2` option is useful, but I want the raw file contents, not the individual lines as elements of a vector.

**Option 2**: `file.show`

```
file.show('file.txt')
# some text on line 1
# some more text on line 2
# even more text on the third line
# etc
```

This output format is what I would like to see, but an option to limit the number of lines, like `n=2` in `readLines`, is missing.

**Option 3**: `system('head')`

```
system('head -n2 file.txt')
# some text on line 1
# some more text on line 2
```

That's exactly the output I would like to get, but I'm not sure if this works on all platforms, and invoking an external command for such a simple task is a bit awkward.

One could combine the `readLines` solution with <s>paste and</s> `cat` to format the output, but this seems excessive. A simple command like `file.head` would be nice, or a `n=2` argument in `file.show`, but neither exists. What is the most elegant and compact way to achieve this in R?

To clarify the goal here: This is for a write up of an R tutorial, where the narrative is something like "... we now have written our data to a new text file, so let's see if it worked by looking at the first couple of lines ...". At this point a simple and compact R expression, using base (**update**: or `tidyverse`) functions, to do exactly this would be very useful.

Comment: (`head`) http://rfunction.com/archives/699 maybe

Comment: `head('file.txt')` only returns `'file.txt'`

Comment: The closest I can think of is one you've already described, but it doesn't require the use of `paste`.  `cat(readLines("file.txt", n = 2), sep = "\n")`.

Comment: You're right, I don't know why I thought one needs both `paste` and `cat`. I modified the question slightly.

Comment: Why is the suggestion by @Benjamin not suitable?  Seems to be just what you want.

Comment: Given that this is for an R tutorial, I suspect @sieste wants to avoid doing a nested function call. If my suspicion is correct, my suggestion minimizes the call, but doesn't quite accomplish the goal. Unfortunately, I don't think there exists an way to meet that goal in base R without writing a custom function. (and that may be more confusing to new users than nested functions).

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. I'll probably settle for @Benjamin s suggestion. Just wanted to make sure I haven't overlooked an obvious solution. If you post as a real answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I am also wondering if there are any functions in tidyverse? I'll add the tidyverse tag and see what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `writeLines` with `readLines`:

```
writeLines(readLines("file.txt", 2))
```

giving:

```
some text on line 1
some more text on line 2
```

This could alternately be written as the following pipeline. It gives the same output:

```
library(magrittr)

"file.txt" %>% readLines(2) %>% writeLines
```